# Can not convert to a function pointer of type

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am basically trying to assign a function pointer to an instance of a typedef I've created. I have some reading to do on the matter, but I can't figure this out.

header:

```
#ifndef FUNCPTRTEST_H
#define FUNCPTRTEST_H

class FuncPtrTest
{
public:
    struct position {
      int x;
      int y;
    } ;

    typedef bool (*CanMove) (position old_pos, position new_pos);
private:
    FuncPtrTest();
    bool FuncExample(position old_pos, position new_pos);
};

#endif // FUNCPTRTEST_H
```

source:

```
#include "funcptrtest.h"

FuncPtrTest::FuncPtrTest()
{
    CanMove a = &FuncPtrTest::FuncExample;
}

bool  FuncPtrTest::FuncExample(position old_pos, position new_pos)
{
    return true;
}
```

error:

```
cannot convert 'bool (FuncPtrTest::*)(FuncPtrTest::position, FuncPtrTest::position)' to 'FuncPtrTest::CanMove {aka bool (*)(FuncPtrTest::position, FuncPtrTest::position)}' in initialization
     CanMove a = &FuncPtrTest::CanMove;
```

Comment: You are declaring a plain function pointer and trying to assign a member function pointer to it.

Comment: A non-member function pointer is not the same as a member function pointer. Reason being that member functions needs a hidden first argument, that becomes the `this` pointer inside the member function. While this hidden first argument is hidden from you, it's still, in a way, part of the member function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, you're trying to assign the address of a member function to a regular function pointer, not a member-function pointer.

Either take the address of a static or non-member function; or change the type to a member-function pointer

```
typedef bool (FuncPtrTest::*CanMove) (position old_pos, position new_pos);
```

In the latter case, you'll need an object to call it on, for example

```
(this->*a)(old_pos, new_pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CanMove a = &FuncPtrTest::FuncExample;
> ```

You cannot initialize it from a non static member function:

```
    static bool FuncExample(position old_pos, position new_pos);
 // ^^^^^^
```